# Connecting to iRobot Create 2 serial port over WebUSB

Tags: irobot-create

I am attempting to connect to the supplied USB serial cable that came with iRobot Create 2 from Chromium 78.0.3904.108 (32-bit) on a Raspberry Pi 4.

From `lsusb`, I was able to determine that the board has vendor ID `0x0403`. From the [Open Interface Spec](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/create_2_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf), I was able to connect via [GtkTerm](https://github.com/Jeija/gtkterm) using the following settings:

- Baud rate: 115200
- Data bits: 8
- Parity: None
- Stop bits: 1
- Flow control: None

That's all well and good, so I shut down GtkTerm and opened Chromium console on an HTTPS origin:

```
const usbDevice = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({filters: [{vendorId: 0x0403}]})
```

So far so good. I got the permission prompt and then a `USBDevice` object back with [BaseClass 0x00](https://www.usb.org/defined-class-codes#anchor_BaseClass00h).

But when I try to `await usbDevice.open()`, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Access denied.
```

No other errors come back. Any ideas how to debug? I am not sure if something in the Raspbian OS failed to free up the resource, or if the device is not supported by WebUSB.

Comment: are you saying that you are trying to connect to a serial port by using a web browser?

Comment: @jsotola correct, I'd like to implement robot controller commands through WebUSB in JavaScript. The robot would launch a browser tab in Chromium and interactions in the UI there would control the robot.